# Why can't I call move assigment from move copy ctor?

Tags: c++17, move-semantics

It looks like a time-saver sometimes if I can call the move assignment op from the move ctor. But when I try, it takes me straight to conventional assignment:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { }
    MyClass(const MyClass& other) { /* do some stuff */ }
    MyClass(MyClass&&      other);                  //move ctor

    const MyClass& operator= (const MyClass& other);
    const MyClass& operator= (MyClass&&      other); //move =
};

MyClass::MyClass(MyClass&& other)                   //move ctor
{
    cout << "Calling move ctor\n";
    *this = other; //<<--THIS IS THE PROBLEM
}

const MyClass& MyClass::operator= (MyClass&& other) //move =
{
    cout << "Calling move =\n";
    return *this;
}

const MyClass& MyClass::operator= (const MyClass& other)
{
    cout << "Calling standard =\n";
    if (this == &other) return *this;
    return *this;
}

MyClass makeVectorToTestMoveCtor() { MyClass V; return V; }

int main ()
{
    MyClass V = makeVectorToTestMoveCtor();

    return 0;
}
```

I can force it with std::move:

```
    cout << "Calling move ctor\n";
    *this = std::move(other);
```

...but if it's not a bad idea, surely I shouldn't need to force it? What should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea - assignment's semantics are about mutating the state of an existing object to make it match another one. A constructor exists to initialize an object that previously didn't exist.

Furthermore, you cannot initialize members with the *member initialization list*, which requires your data members to be default-constructible and non-`const`.

If anything, it would make more sense to define the assignment in terms of the constructor, something like:

```
foo& foo::operator=(foo&& rhs)
{
    this->~foo();
    new (this) foo{std::move(rhs};
}
```

For the above snippet, you need to be careful to not trigger UB, though: [Placement new and assignment of class with const member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473621/placement-new-and-assignment-of-class-with-const-member)

---

In general, I would just define both operators separately unless you can let the compiler generate them for you.

Comment: Don't do that (destroy then construct).  It isn't exception safe.  It may also be broken when doing self-assignment.

Comment: @Nevin: I am not advocating for that, I am saying that it would make more sense to define assignment in terms of constructor rather than the other way around. The link I posted shows that the destroy+placement new is indeed dangerous. My last sentence advocates for manual definition of both functions, or following the rule of zero

Answer (score 0):

Construction is the more fundamental operation.  You have to have a constructed object before you can assign to or from it.  Write your assignment in terms of construction and not the other way around.