# May I call destructor from move assignement operator?

Tags: c++11, destructor, move-semantics

Well I have non-trivial destructor in my class.

May I do something like:

```
Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&& from) {
    ~Foo()
    // Copy the stuff and cleanup "from"
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to avoid code duplication.

Also, I could write some cleanup function, but if I can call destructor then what for?

Comment: If you call the destructor, the object ceases to exist, you need to construct a new one in its place. You can use placement new with a move constructor for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could, in principle, call a destructor this way, if you then use placement new to construct the object back into the now-empty space. Something like this:

```
Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&& from) {
  void* p = this;
  ~Foo();
  return *(new(p) Foo(std::move(from)));  // calls Foo(Foo&&) constructor
}
```

There are significant limitations to this approach - see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47473621/placement-new-and-assignment-of-class-with-const-member). For example, it would exhibit undefined behavior if `Foo` has non-static members of `const`-qualified or reference type; or if this operator is actually applied to a base class subobject of a class derived from `Foo`. For this and other reasons, this is not commonly done.