Is this an abuse of placement new?
Let's say I am relying on a class that has a private constant member.
class FirstOrderFilter {
public:
    FirstOrderFilter(double tau);

    double Step(double in);
    void Reset(double in = 0);
private:
    double in_prev;
    double out_prev;
    const double tau;
};

I'd like to use an instance of that class, but when I need to reset it, I'd like to totally replace the instance of that object:
FirstOrderFilter filter(1.0);
// do stuff
filter = FirstOrderFilter(0.5);

I think that's a reasonable thing to do.  It ensures that you completely replace the object, avoiding any internal states that could otherwise persist.  It's similar to preferring case 1 over case 2 in this code:
std::string str;
// do stuff
str = std::string(); // case 1: replace the object, versus
str.erase();         // case 2: rely on the object to reset itself

But when I compile that, the class' private implementation gets in the way, producing:
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:34: error: use of deleted function ‘FirstOrderFilter& FirstOrderFilter::operator=(FirstOrderFilter&&)’
   17 |     filter = FirstOrderFilter(0.5);
      |                                  ^
main.cpp:1:7: note: ‘FirstOrderFilter& FirstOrderFilter::operator=(FirstOrderFilter&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
    1 | class FirstOrderFilter {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:1:7: error: non-static const member ‘const double FirstOrderFilter::tau’, cannot use default assignment operator
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:34: note: use ‘-fdiagnostics-all-candidates’ to display considered candidates
   17 |     filter = FirstOrderFilter(0.5);
      |                                  ^

That's clear.  Because of its private const member, it can't generate an operator= that doesn't violate const rules.  But a user shouldn't really care about that implementation.
An obvious work-around is using pointers instead of direct objects:
FirstOrderFilter* filter = new FirstOrderFilter(1.0);
// ...
delete filter;
filter = new FirstOrderFilter(0.5);

or
auto filter = std::make_unique<FirstOrderFilter>(1.0);
// ...
filter = std::make_unique<FirstOrderFilter>(0.5);

But this has two disadvantages:

It calls free and malloc and to create the new object (slower)
I need to change syntax in all of my other uses of filter because it's now a pointer.

A better solution could be the use of placement new to avoid memory allocation completely.
FirstOrderFilter filter(1.0);
//...
filter.~FirstOrderFilter();
new (&filter) FirstOrderFilter(0.5);

But I'm told this is highly unusual, as placement new is mostly for implementing your own memory allocation (ring buffers, shared memory, etc), and not for normal everyday use for things like object replacements.
Is this a reasonable usage of placement new?  Or is there a more obvious solution that I'm missing (perhaps a const_cast or mutable something-or-other).

Pretty sure the placement new usage is still illegal if you change the value of the const member and access it through the same name.

This is an allowed use of placement new, but it is rarely seen and can be considered unusual for this reason. You should still use the returned pointer if possible, which will be well behaved. What you are allowed to do with the name filter after the placement new is limited and depends on the version of C++ you are using.

The typical solution to this problem is to not use const data members in the first place. The variable is private, you can force its immutability by not providing any setter. There isn't tangible benefit to making it const.

That implies it's best practice to always avoid const members in case someone might want to reset our class.  I haven't heard that before, but I can see how that could make sense.

@Stewart that's common.  The idea that private members don't need to be const.  That said, your use of placement new is legal and well-defined, but unusual.  Whether it's "abuse" is a matter of opinion.

@Stewart C++ core guidelines explicitly discourage the usage of const members. The guideline mentions copy/move operation, but that's your exact case: copy assignment.

The "unusual" part is that if you have a pointer or reference to filter, the compiler can assume that the const member never changes (because it is constant!). This might be a use case for std::launder (which almost nobody seems to understand, for example Bjarne does not  :-).

You'll have to launder all references to the object after overwriting it because the compiler will assume that the const has not changed. And that is so clunky that you wouldn't want it anyway. The real problem is declaring something const while reserving the right to modify it! Pick a side. Either it is const (and never modify it), or it is not const (and modify it all you like).

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010310/is-using-a-placement-new-as-a-copy-assignment-operator-bad

@Stewart  The best practice is not to avoid const members in case someone wants to reset (an instance of) the class.   The best practice is to avoid const members if there is ever any reason to reset the class instance.   Use of a const member, by definition, means that it may be safely assumed (e.g. by the implementation, or - for that matter - humans examining code which uses the class) that the member will not be updated during lifetime of its containing object.

Alternative to pointer is std::optional: No allocations, and also different syntax as pointer.

The practical problem is that
FirstOrderFilter foo{4.2};
bar(foo);
std::cout << foo.getTau();

is allowed to assume foo.tau is still 4.2 after the call to bar, because it's a const member.
That's what const members mean, and permitting that optimization is probably the only reason to use them.
If bar might have magically mutated that const member where your code can't see it (whether by placement new or any other mechanism), you have an entirely predictable problem.
To do this safely, you need to somehow communicate to the caller that foo.tau might have changed.
The std::launder option isn't great: bar would need to return a pointer to the same object and the caller would have to only refer to the object via the pointer afterwards. This is obviously error-prone and unwieldy.
You can see P0532 On Launder (PDF) for more discussion of the problem and why std::launder doesn't really solve it.
Another possibility is to wrap the object in a union, or variant, or optional or something to make it clear that it could be replaced by a different instance when you're not looking - but you need to pass the wrapper everywhere, and again it's unwieldy.
A much better solution is to not use const for things you actually want to change sometimes.

PS. there's a related optimization, devirtualization, that has exactly the same problem (if you replace a dynamically-typed object with one of another type). This makes intuitive sense if you think of a vtable pointer (or equivalent RTTI implementation detail) as a const member. Anyway, don't do that either.
